# Interpreting GIT's Branching Summary

Tags: git, shell

After running the command:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --branches
```

I get the following output:

```
* af2a175 - (HEAD, origin/master, origin/develop, origin/HEAD, master, feature/feature-a, develop) Commit message. (3 days ago) <username>
```

How should I interpret the:

```
(HEAD, origin/master, origin/develop, origin/HEAD, master, feature/feature-a, develop)
```

bit?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: i've read parts of the documentation. haven't read the entire thing. i could've searched it, but would have a hard time coming up with a search term to locate the pertinent info ...

Comment: The git-log documentation for `%d` (which is the bit that outputs those entries) would have been a good place to start. Which would then have pointed you to the git-log `--decorate` option.

Comment: @EtanReisner gotcha, thanks. reviewing that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to indicate the tips of the branches that point at that specific commit.  Currently, your local HEAD reference, `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, `origin/HEAD`, your local `master` branch, your local `feature/feature-a` and your local `develop` branch point there.

From Git's point of view, it would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: bam, grokked! thanks for this snippet of goooooollllld ... `mas uno`

Comment: this is a "live" view of the remote origins, correct? just confirming ... "live" at the time of executing the command.

Comment: Yes.  Insofar as your current system knows, this is the state of the repository.  If you do a `git pull` and that state changes (that is, the tips of the branches advance elsewhere), you'll get different output.  By the way, you can recreate stuff like this [at this link.](http://onlywei.github.io/explain-git-with-d3/)  The visual layout may be simpler to digest.

Comment: got what i needed to know from this discussion. thanks much @makoto! will play with that visualization though, looks interesting ...

Answer (score 1):

It means that all those branches's `HEAD` are at this commit (the #af2a175 one):

for example I can tell that the following local branches:

- `master`, `develop` are at this commit AND were pushed to remote, since, are also listed: `origin/master`, `origin/develop`
- `feature/feature-a` is also at this commit BUT has not yet been pushed because, no sign of `origin/feature/feature-a`